# How can a new person get up to speed on abbreviations?

Tags: communication

While a number of acronyms and abbreviations are widely accepted and understood, others are used within specific fields to save space and time, I assume. In writing especially, the author should state originally what the entire phrase is but often this step is skipped. Is there a guide or even app that will translate for those of us who aren't that kind of communicator? (Or is this a setting on my computer??)

Comment: Do you need anything beyond google? Just search for "acronym XYZ" and you're pretty sure to get results for any industry or subject matter that has an acronym of XYZ.

Comment: "Is there a guide or even app" - NAFAIK. You can try Wikipedia, Wiktionary, Urban Dictionary, or even this site for common business abbreviations like PTO, FTE, CFO, etc.

Comment: this sounds like a bad idea for an app, i hope nobody builds this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about an app to expand acronyms and has nothing to do with navigating the workplace.

Comment: Best practice is for all acronyms to be spelt out the first time they are used in any document.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that many acronyms have multiple meanings. You/your company should create a standard definition sheet that covers what is used within your field.

If this is a more generic question, then I'd say use https://www.acronymfinder.com/

Comment: I was about to write this answer. "It is your company's/boss's job to provide the documentation"

Comment: I'm assuming the OP meant internal acronyms that is particular to the company not standard acronyms.

Comment: @Dan That was the assumption I made as well, but I thought it helpful to include Acronym Finder as I've used it many times over the years.

Comment: I publish a widely unread "glossary" for our staff.  Also - multiple meanings is an issue.  In broadcasting, "SWAG = Stuff We Always Get" (customer giveaways).  In software engineering "SWAG = Scientific Wild-A**ed Guess"

Comment: @Dan That's a strange assumption to make, because the OP also asked for an *app* which expands these acronyms. It would be absurd to ask on a public site about an app that expands internal acronyms.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the environment if there is a list of acronyms somewhere. If I encounter a lot of strange acronyms when I first start a job, I usually ask around to see if anyone has a list of the meanings. When I first went to work for the US Navy as a civilian employee, I found a book called the DicNavAb (Dictionary of Naval Abbreviations) which was invaluable the first three or four years. Sadly it was last updated in 1984. Many Government offices have listings because the acronyms are so extensive in the government.

Another source of the definitions are long formal documents such as reports. These are more likely to follow the convention of defining in the first use or in an appendix. In particular documents of a legal nature will be more likely to do this.

You should also ask people what the acronym stands for. Don't necessarily interrupt, but write down the acronym and ask the person after the meeting. Keep a running list so that you don't have to ask twice.

The Internet is a good source as well. Google the acronym. You have to use your judgement here as many acronyms have multiple meanings in different business domains. If you aren't sure, go to a coworker or you boss and tell them the two meanings you found and ask them which is correct in your current context. This website can also help:
https://www.acronymfinder.com/